# Naming convention for List variables

Tags: java, naming-conventions

I have a question that may seem pretty trivial to many, but it's one that has made me think repeatedly about the readability of the code that I write.

Lets assume that I have a class that encapsulates details of an entity, such as an employee, called `EmployeeDetails`. (Note - I also have a class named `Employee` which exists at the DAO layer. I do not want to return any DAO level classes from my service methods, which is why I created the `EmployeeDetails` class to be returned from my service layer methods. I also wanted to avoid confusion between class names by keeping the service and DAO layer class names distinct).

I also have a service level method that, given a list of Employee numbers, returns a `List<EmployeeDetails>`. My question is this - what is the best coding convention for naming the return variable? I had two options in mind.

1. `employeeDtls` - I do not like this because the person who reads my code may think that "employeeDtls" refers to an instance of `EmployeeDetails` instead of a list.
2. `employeeDtlsList` - I do not like this because it seems "too wordy".

Does anyone follow any specific coding conventions for variables? What is the most widely used naming convention for list variables?

Answer (score 2):

Well...let's consider what we're modeling here.

A general rule of thumb, is that if it's a collection, then it should be pluralized and scoped to the contents of what you expect.

So, that'd make your variable name `List<EmployeeDetails> details` or `List<EmployeeDetails> employees`.  If you can help it, try to avoid the compound name, unless that truly and concretely represents what it is you're getting back.

If you were using the [Data Transfer Object](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) model, and you had named it something along the lines of `EmployeeDto`, then the name of the variable would be more specific at `employees`, as you expect back some collection of *something* representing an `Employee` (at its core).

Answer (score 1):

I usually name the return variable `result`, for all methods:

```
List<EmployeeDetails> result;
```

The reason is that it's obvious which list I'm adding to, and that it's gong to be returned, especially if there are multiple lists within the method.

This also conforms to good practice by naming things for what they represent, rather than what are they are. Your idea is a bit like naming an int variable as `intVariable`. Naming it simply `result` means you can change they type of the result, eg to `Set<EmployeeDetails>` without any refactoring of the name.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather call the class `EmployeeDetail` so it is a singular noun which represent "detail information" of an employee.

Then the variable naming will be straight forward for its collection : `employeeDetails`

In case I really encounter a class named in plural form (for which I usually try to avoid), I usually use `~List` as the variable name for the collection of such type.  Although it is a bit too verbose, at least it doesn't cause any confusion.

Answer (score -2):

Use `DTO (Data Transfer Object)` pattern to carry the data of underlying entity.

In your case, `EmployeeDetails` should be `EmployeeDTO`

Take a look at discussion [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171457/what-is-the-point-of-using-dto-data-transfer-objects)